# Image not loading in chrome from css background property

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using "background: #BDBDBD url(image.png) top left no-repeat" this css property for two div elements which has width and height set. On clicking a button I am changing the width of both the nested divs dynamically by making the function run continuously with the help of setInterval(). The image is not loading in chrome but it works fine in firefox and IE .. Many searches convey that using background image in chrome is not working but none of those solutions seems to work.

```
<div id="boxes">
          <div id="dialog" class="window" style="overflow: auto">

              <div id="progressBar" class="meter-wrap" style="display: block;position: relative; margin: auto;">
                 <div class="meter-value" style="background-color: #05C; width: 40%">
                    <div class="meter-text">
                       Loading... 
                     </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="meter-text-message">
                        Loading...
              </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.meter-wrap, .meter-value, .meter-text {
        width: 155px; height: 30px;
}

.meter-wrap, .meter-value {
    background: #bdbdbd url('/sf-images/tracker/inline_progress_bar.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

js code:

```
function setProgressBar() {
    var pgBar = jQuery("#progressBar");
    pgBar.show();
    running = true;
    var inter = null;

    function run() {
        pgBar.find(".meter-value").css("width", progress + "%");
        pgBar.find(".meter-text").text(progress + "%");
        if (progress == 100) {
            jQuery(".meter-text-message").html("Complete");
            clearInterval(inter);
            running = false;
        }
    }
    inter = setInterval(run, 50);
}
```

Found that the image is not loading for first time, I made the div element visible with the image as background by another method. After that , when I execute the above js method image loads properly.

Comment: You're setting an inline background-color style on .meter-value - is that maybe affecting it? Remove the inline style and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Open the page in Chrome, right click the element giving you problems and choose inspect element and look in the right panel for the CSS. It will show you which properties are applied and which are being over ridden by something else. Chances are Billy is right and specificity is causing your issue here. (yet another good reason to avoid inline styles)

Comment: .meter-value has width of 0 so the blue(#05e) color won't be visible I need that because , on the background grey area I want to show the blue color like progress bar. When I inspect the dom, I made the div.#dialog to block at that point the image is rendered only after calling the setProgressBar() it is breaking i guess. Thanks for quick response

Comment: Rick I tried removing the inline color in the inspect element option still the image is not loaded, I could see the grey color though (#BDBDBD)

Comment: From my above comment it is clear that the div is taking the color mentioned in css style class .meter-wrap and .meter-value but it is not taking the image.. The path of the image should be correct because it works in firefox and IE..